# Kotlin Variable Value Different From What I Assign (Getted From Another Activity Class)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm very new to Kotlin and I have really annoying problem right now. I don't know how to tell this exact way I'f there is any similar case I can correct this question. My problem is like that: I have 1 activity that get data from my device, and when it's get data it send this data to another activity, but this second activity not always on to UI, if user click button on the 1 activity then 2. activity opens. While 2. activity is not active the data getted from device not sending the 2.activity. There is array and array counter on  my 2.activity which will be hold the data. When data readed correct array counter is increasing one. And I'm check this counter the show this value on the screen. In the 2.activity the function that getting data show counter value exactly but the other function (which will be check and display data on the screen) shows 0 always. I think there are kinda 2 active activity at the same time but I'm not sure. Code representation as follows:

**1.Activity**

```
OnCreate{
....
//Get Button Click
    Button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, 2.Activity_Class)
        startActivity(intent)
        send = true
    }



//On Data Trigger
//Send Data To 2.Activity if is opened
   if (send) {
                val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                handler.postDelayed({
                    // Run your task here
                   2.Activity_Class.getData(data.value.toHexString())
                }, 1)
            }
```

**2.Activity**

```
var counter=0

showData(){
//When I'm writing counter in here counter = 0 always
if(counter>10){
  //Do work in here
  }
}


getData(data: String){
//Interpret Data ...
counter++
//This counter is correct (It's showing correct on log)
}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem right, and like as I say I'm not sure if it is correct way to define that problem.

Comment: There is a wall between Activities. You shouldn't even be able to get a reference to the other activity instance, so I don't know how you were calling it in your code above. Read up on communicating between them. It requires sending bundles through intents. you can also set a result that is returned to an Activity higher on the stack. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles

Comment: I know putExtra int intent but i need real-time communication between Activities, so putExtra not solving my problem unfortunately.

Comment: The Activity that is not on screen will not run any of its UI code, so it doesn’t really make sense to describe real-time communication between Activities.

Comment: In my case the other activity is BLE listener, and it's triggering when data arrive after that send this data to activity (which is on the screen), but the other function also running. My problem like the other function send the data to current activity's function but when I'm trying to read that data in current activity it shows always zero, but in calling funciton it's not zero. There is kinda 2 same activities running at the same time but not sure.

Comment: Only one Activity runs at a time. They are in a stack. Now it’s possible you launched a thread using the other Activity that is still running after that Activity went down in the stack. But that thread is leaked after any configuration change like the screen rotating. I would use a single Activity with separate Fragments, and use a ViewModel to handle the communication so it stays alive and doesn’t leak anything through configuration changes.

Comment: I will try this, thank you.